# How To Inventory a Stockpile?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is there a way to see *all* the contents of a stockpile in *Dwarf Fortress*?

I'd like to get an inventory of my Metal Bar stock.

Comment: Another (possibly faster, possibly exploit) method is to almost build a wall. Of course if you have 100+ bars you can't tell exactly how many, but if you just want to know if you've got enough steel to make the 15 pieces of armor this is a quick way to find out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [<kbd>z</kbd> stock screen](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Stock) can indeed break it down by bar type. Make sure you actually have your "Bars" section selected, and your <kbd>tab</kbd> mode set to group items. In addition, make sure that your [bookkeeper](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Bookkeeper) is working with adequate [precision](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Stock#Bookkeeping_.26_precision) to view individual items. Here is an example from the [DF Magma Wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Main_Page) showing a [breakdown of seed types](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Stock#Layout):

[image]

Other than this, there is no way to view all contents of a given stockpile.

Comment: I just have 'Bars', and it does not break it down. However, after further research, I have learned about Precision: http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/Stock Thank you, your answer led me there.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten that precision hides more precise breakdowns! I'll incorporate that into my answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

This function is implemented in the latest versions of DfHack, just <kbd>q</kbd> the stockpile and you get an <kbd>i</kbd> option that will give you the inventory of the stockpile, "Show inventory" at the bottom right.

[image]

Stockpile inventory:
[image]

You can find DfHack on Github: https://github.com/DFHack/dfhack/releases